# Is there a difference between IAS from armor and weapon IAS?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some items that increase attack speed work, and others don't?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70095/why-do-some-items-that-increase-attack-speed-work-and-others-dont)

In Diablo 2, there was a difference between *Increase Attack Speed* (IAS) on weapons and IAS from other sources (such as Armor/Jewelry).

I started to wonder about the same in Diablo 3, when I looked at weapons that have an IAS property, such as this axe: http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/the-wedge

As you can see, the item-information states: `1.46-1.47 Attacks per Second`, which is more than an axe has without the IAS (`1.3` in that case). Equipping such a weapon while having other items with +IAS, won't change that number. This leads me to the conclusion that there might be two separate IAS calculations going on. The IAS on the weapon changes the **base weapon speed**, while all other IAS is multiplied with that base-speed.

Which in turn would make IAS on the weapon itself more valuable.

Does anybody know how the formula for attack-speed works? Are all sources of IAS being treated equally, or is there indeed a difference between weapon-IAS and armor-IAS?