# How to know if attack speed works on Legendary items listed in AH?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some Legendary items in Diablo 3, like for example [Inna's Glory](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-glory), are bugged. They declare to have **Attack Speed**, but in reality bonus is not working when equipped.

I just read the changelog of patch 1.03 and it seems they have fixed this bug, but only for new dropped items.

> - Legendary items with the +Attack Speed bonus will now correctly provide a bonus to attack speed - *Please note that this fix will only
>     affect new Legendary drops. Existing Legendary items will be addressed
>     in future patch.*

In the meanwhile Blizzard develop a retroactive fix for bugged items, if I want to buy any Legendary item in Auction House, how can I understand if the item listed is new (AS working as intended) or old (AS not working)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do some items that increase attack speed work, and others don't?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70095/why-do-some-items-that-increase-attack-speed-work-and-others-dont)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any item that has the affix "Increases attack speed" increases the attack speed of the item it's on, meaning if it's on a weapon, only that weapon will be increased even if you dual wield. This also means that any pieces of armour with "Increases attack speed" won't have any effect, as they can't attack.

Any item with the prefix "Attack speed increased" increases the attack speed of all equipped weapons, therefore, if it's on a piece of armour it will still work.

So:

- IAS - Increases attack speed = BAD (except on weapons)
- ASI - Attack speed increased = GOOD

[Many](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4552401326) [different](http://www.vilepickle.com/blog/2012/06/06/00159-diablo-3-attack-speed-modifier-armor-not-working-correctly#.T-KT2LUth8E) [sources.](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4551470684)

Comment: Is the implication that Blizzard fixed this for new items by just getting rid of "increased attack speed" and replacing it with "attack speed increased"?

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yes, all new armour pieces should drop with Attack speed increased, and at some point in the future Blizzard will go through and replace all existing increases attack speed items with attack speed increased items.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I just added in 3 links that I found in a couple of minutes of searching, while none of them are official (I don't know if there's been official word that this is what's wrong), it shows that pretty much everyone has realised what I've said in my answer.

Comment: @MarkTrapp the presence of both affixes dates back to launch. One works all of the time, the other only works on some slots.